# Why is there a $z_0\in \mathbb H$, such that $g(z_0)=z_0\implies g=id$?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, hyperbolic-geometry, fixed-point-theorems

Take $\mathbb H$ the Poincaré upper half plane and $G$ a Fuchsian group acting on it.

I don't see why we can pick a $z_0\in \mathbb H$ such that
$$ g(z_0)=z_0\implies g=id,\quad \forall g\in G.$$

Comment: Your question seems to make no much sense: we *can pick* an element  $\;z_0\in\Bbb H\;$ such that $\;g(z_0)=z_0\implies g=\text{Id}\;$ ?? What does this mean, anyway? Did you mean to ask: " **If there exists** $\;z\_0\in\Bbb H\;$ **such that** $\;g(z_0)=z_0\;$ **then....something**?

Comment: I am reading a text that claims we can pick an $z_0\in \mathbb H$ such that $gz_0=z_0\implies g=id$. I can't see why we can...

Comment: @ge But that doesn't even make sense: the book says that you can pick an element in the set such that...it wll make *any element* in the group to be the unit?? That's impossible, of course...I think you are misunderstanding something. What book is that, please?

Comment: I am reading the lecture notes *Hyperbolic Geometry* by Caroline series [(link)](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masbb/Papers/MA448.pdf). The claim is the first sentence of Definition 5.4 on page 77.

Comment: The claim in other words: there is a point $z_0\in \mathbb H$, which is not a fixed point of any nontrivial $g\in G$. This doesn't strike me as obvious.

Comment: Ok, that seems to be way another thing: what they say there, after a quick reading, is that there exists an element $\;z_0\in\Bbb H\;$ which is **not a fixed element of the whole group $\;G\;$ *except the unit element* ....this makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a $z_0$ such that the only element of $G$ that leaves it in place is the identity.

Consider the upper half-plane to be a model of the hyperbolic plane, and $G$ acting isometrically on it. If any $g\in G$ fixes three points that are not (hyperbolically) collinear, then it must be the identity. Thus, for every $g\ne\rm id$, the set
$$ \{z \mid gz = z \} $$
is contained in a hyperbolic line (it need no be the whole line, though: it can be empty or a singleton), and therefore it has Lebesgue measure zero.

Since $G$ is countable, this means that
$$ \bigcup_{g\in G\setminus\{\rm id\}} \{ z \mid gz = z \} $$
-- that is, the set of points that are fixed by *any* non-identity element of $G$ -- also has measure zero. In particular it cannot be the entire $\mathbb H$, so you can choose a $z_0$ outside of it.

---

(Of course measure theory can be considered a bit overkill for showing that a countable collection of lines cannot cover the plane. Instead we could also look at a *single* line that is not among the fixpoint lines -- each fixpoint line intersects it in at most one point, so only countably many of the points on that line will be excluded).

Comment: I understand what you're doing. However, I've not yet seen why $G$ should be countable.

Comment: Oh wait, $G\subset SL(2,\mathbb R)$ of course..

Comment: @gebruiker: There are different definitions of Fuchsian groups -- some require $G$ to be finitely generated, in which case countability is obvious. In other cases it is just a discrete subgroup of $PSL_2$, which must be countable because $PSL_2$ is separable (because it is a continuous image of an algebraic variety in $\mathbb R^4$).

Comment: Yes thank you. You cleared things up for me quite a lot. It helped me find another method more in line with the lecture notes I'm reading, (i.e. without countability arguments). I'll post that one here too. But your answer helped me get there so I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

A Fuchsian group is not only discrete, but also acts properly discontinously on $\mathbb H$.

So take a nontrivial compact subset $K\subset \mathbb H$ and assume that $$\forall k\in K\,\exists g\in G\setminus\{id\}\mid g(k)=k.$$ Since any nontrivial $g\in G$ has at most two fixed points, this implies that $$\#\{g\mid g(K)\cap K\neq \emptyset\}=\infty. $$ This is a contradiction, so there must be a $z_0\in K\subset \mathbb H$ such that $$g(z_0)=z_0\implies g=id.$$